Automatic Date Filtering
I'm working on an application where I need a filter to be applied automatically when selecting a date, without needing to press Enter. Currently the filter only fires when I press Enter after entering the date in the search calendar.
%{title: "Study Date", field: "studydate", headerFilter: true, width: 150, editor: "date", editorParams: %{ format: "mm/dd/yyyy", verticalNavigation: "table", }}

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
